# Want to create a function to pass the same dataset through

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a function, that will do the same thing to different columns within the same dataset. The only problem is that I am getting the error `object Income not found.`
What is wrong? Code is below.

```
dataFilter <- function(data){
    rawData %>% group_by(date) %>% 
    summarise(paste(data,"Count" = n(data)))
}

Data <- dataFilter(Income)
```

Comment: (Will that work with `dplyr`'s non-standard evaluation in `summarize`? I thought not ...) JohnLaw, it's generally a bad idea to access `rawData` (assuming that's the data read from a CSV) from the global environment in this fashion. I suggest instead you use `function(x, column)` and reference it internally as `x`. Next, you might benefit from reading the standard-evaluation (and NSE, for that matter) methods of using `dplyr` verbs, since it won't work this way. Ref: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: From your  natural language description, it sounds as though `base::sapply` would achieve this goal. However ,,, no data,,, no good answer.

Comment: I suggest that with grouping, it would better be served by `aggregate`, `by`, `ave`, or one of those functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's generally a bad idea to hard-code and use a variable from the global environment within the function. For starters, it might work well during basic development, but it is nearly impossible to test well, and troubleshooting problems is a pain. (For instance, if this function is called from a non-global environment that *also* has a variable named `rawData` in it, then Murphy's Law states that it will use the version of the data you do *not* want it to use.)

So first thing I'd suggest is to accept the data to manipulate as an argument to the function. Since you're using `tidyverse` (and arguably even if you weren't), it is often suggested to "keep the data *first*", so changing your formals to `function(df, column)` is a good start.

On a similar note, hard-coding `date` as a grouping variable is similarly problematic. It is slightly less problematic than `rawData`, but not by a lot. (I know it's easy to do it this way, I am recovering from this laziness in several of my local packages.) So I suggest you make `date` an argument of the function as well.

This type of function is specifically given as an example in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html (just over half-way down on today's view), as:

```
my_mutate <- function(df, expr) {
  expr <- enquo(expr)
  mean_name <- paste0("mean_", quo_name(expr))
  sum_name <- paste0("sum_", quo_name(expr))

  mutate(df,
    !! mean_name := mean(!! expr),
    !! sum_name := sum(!! expr)
  )
}
```

The translation will generalize things *a little*, removing the hard-coded `date` from things.

```
dataFilter <- function(df, grp, col) {
    grp <- enquo(grp)
    col <- enquo(col)
    mean_name <- paste0(quo_name(col), "Average")
    group_by(df, !! grp) %>%
      summarize(!! mean_name := mean(!! col))
}
rawData %>%
  dataFilter(date, Income)
```

Some other considerations, with `dplyr`-programming: if you `group` it, do you intend for it to come out still-grouped, or do you want to add `%>% ungroup()` after the summarize? Will you always annihilate the current grouping, or do you want to check for data that is already grouped before you group it internally?

Lastly, as @42- just commented, "no data, no good answer". I can't test this truly for your data since we don't have it.